# Adding record to a data table whose columns are generated at runtime(any sample)

Tags: c#

I have a datatable where the columns names are getting added at runtime

How can I populate record to such a data table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean a form builder? if so there are many apps already existing such as

http://www.dotnetgoodies.com/form_builder_details.aspx

but if you are that much desperate you will have to create your own. then at least four tables will make a simple design.

- DataTables (Id, Name)
- DataColumns (Id, DataTableName, Name)
- DataRecords (Id, DataTableName)
- DataColumnsRecords (Id, DataRecordId, DataColumnId, DataValue)